# Upgrade Postgres Extension / Install Specific Version

Tags: postgresql

1) How do you upgrade a postgres extension?
2) How do you install a specific extension version?

In production the version of hstore is out of date.

```
=> select * from pg_available_extensions where name ='hstore';
  name  | default_version | installed_version |                     comment
--------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------
 hstore | 1.3             | 1.1               | data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs
```

All the other environments hstore is already at 1.3 so I don't have a way to test if `create extension hstore;` is all I need.

I'd like to test the upgrade first and ran Postgres 9.4.4 through Docker

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres:9.4.4

docker run -it --rm --link some-postgres:postgres postgres:9.4.4 psql -h postgres -U postgres
```

but hstore 1.3 was the default version

```
  name  | default_version | installed_version |                     comment
--------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------
 hstore | 1.3             | 1.3               | data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs
```

Answer (score 18):

1. **To upgrade a postgres extension**

   - install the latest version
     `ALTER EXTENSION hstore UPDATE;`
   - install a specific version

     - list available extensions
       `SELECT * FROM pg_available_extension_versions WHERE name ='hstore';`
     - install the specific version
       `ALTER EXTENSION hstore UPDATE TO '1.3';`
2. **Install a specific version older than the default version**

   - Download the version from the postgres repo to the pg_config extension directory.
     `wget --directory-prefix /usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension/ \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/postgres/postgres/REL9_2_STABLE/contrib/hstore/hstore--1.1.sql`
   - Check available versions
     `SELECT * FROM pg_available_extension_versions WHERE name ='hstore';`
   - Install specific version
     `CREATE EXTENSION hstore WITH VERSION '1.1';`